# I am unable to send the the FormData() object to the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am defining my API like this :
api.js

```
//here we will make API calls with the help of axios interceptor

import axios from "axios";

import { API_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGES, SERVICE_URLS } from "../constants/config";

// backend url
const API_URL = "http://localhost:8000";

// Each instance is a separate client that can carry its own configuration and options like base URLs, timeouts, and headers. Then, we can reuse the configuration for API calls using the same instance.

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL,
  timeout: 10000,
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json, form-data",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    // "Content-Type": "'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'"
  },
});

// interceptor for api requests
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  function (config) {
    return config;
  },
  function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

// interceptor for api response
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  function (response) {
    // stop the loader if there is any
    return processResponse(response);
  },
  function (error) {
    // stop loader if there is any
    return Promise.reject(processError(error));
  }
);

// function in case of success
const processResponse = (response) => {
  if (response?.status === 200) {
    //api call was successful
    return { isSuccess: true, data: response.data };
  } else {
    return {
      isFailure: true,
      status: response?.status,
      msg: response?.msg,
      code: response?.code,
    };
  }
};

const processError = (error) => {
  if (error.response) {
    // Request made and server responded with status other that falls out of range 2.x.x(ex:200)
    console.log("Error IN RESPONSE", error.toJSON());
    return {
      isError: true,
      msg: API_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGES.responseFailure,
      code: error.response.status,
    };
  } else if (error.request) {
    //Request was made from frontend but no response was received from backend ie may be the frontend didn't connect with backend
    //so no request was sent to backend that's why no code response from backend
    console.log("Error IN REQUEST", error.toJSON());
    return {
      isError: true,
      msg: API_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGES.requestFailure,
      code: "",
    };
  } else {
    // someting happened in setting up the request from frontend  that triggers an error so no request was made
    // no reuest was sent to backend , therefore backend didn't give any response code
    console.log("Error IN NETWORK", error.toJSON());
    return {
      isError: true,
      msg: API_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGES.networkError,
      code: "",
    };
  }
};

const API = {};
//api request
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(SERVICE_URLS)) {
  API[key] = (body, showUploadProgress, showDownloadProgress) =>
    axiosInstance({
      method: value.method,
      url: value.url,
      data: body,
      responseType: value.responseType,
      onUploadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
        if (showUploadProgress) {
          let percentageCompleted = Math.round(
            (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total
          );
          showUploadProgress(percentageCompleted);
        }
      },
      onDownloadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
        if (showDownloadProgress) {
          let percentageCompleted = Math.round(
            (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total
          );
          showDownloadProgress(percentageCompleted);
        }
      },
    });
}

export { API };
```

where my constants are coming from config.js

config.js

```
// API _NOTIFICATION_MESSAGES

export const API_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGES = {
  loading: {
    title: "Loading...",
    message: "Data is being loaded,Please wait",
  },
  success: {
    title: "Success",
    message: "Data successfully loaded",
  },
  responseFailure: {
    title: "Error",
    message:
      "An error occured while fetching response from the server.Please try again",
  },
  requestFailure: {
    title: "Error",
    message: "An error occured while parsing request data",
  },
  networkError: {
    title: "Error",
    message:
      "Unable to connect with the server.Please check internet connectivity and try again later",
  },
};

//API SERVICE CALL
//SAMPLE REQUEST
// NEED SERVICE CALL :{url:"/",method:"POST/GET/PUT/DELETE" params:true/false,query:true/false}

export const SERVICE_URLS = {
  userSignup: { url: "/signup", method: "POST" },
  userLogin: { url: "login", method: "POST" },
  uploadFile: { url: "/file/upload", method: "POST" },
};
```

Now I am calling the API.uploadFile() in CreatePost.jsx
CreatePost.jsx

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getImage = async () => {
    if (file) {
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append("name", file.name);
      data.append("file", file);

      let response;
      //calling API for uploading image to database
      try {
        response = await API.uploadFile(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }

      console.log(response);
    }
  };
  getImage();
}, [file]);
```

I have defined the state file in which I am setting input file with onChange event

```
<label htmlFor="fileInput">
    <Add fontSize="large" color="action" />
</label>

<input
    type="file"
    id="fileInput"
    style={{ display: "none" }}
    onChange={(e) => {
        setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    }}
/>
```

But when I am uploading file from the computer, it is unable to send the data object to the server and in the api call the file is not going in the payload and it is throwing me error

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data') TypeError: Cannot
> read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
> at getImage (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:809:33)